# How can I aggregate cells to get an average percentage with Pandas?

Tags: pandas

I would like to find the average enrollment rate of each ethnic group per state. I have the percentage of ethnic enrollment for each university in that state. How can I find the average percentage enrollment of each ethnic group by state with Pandas?

**example with made up numbers, just trying to show what I mean

```
School   State White AA Black Hispanic
School1 NJ    .46   .22  .19  .4
School2 NJ    .32   .11  .07  .12
School2 NY    .11   .29  .13  .16
School2 NJ    .12   .13  .07  .09


Output:
State White AA Black Hispanic
NJ    .46   .22  .19  .4
NY    .22   .14  .12  .22
```

Comment: are you after: `df.groupby('State').mean()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [82]: df.groupby(['School','State']).mean()
Out[82]:
               White    AA  Black  Hispanic
School  State
School1 NJ      0.46  0.22   0.19     0.400
School2 NJ      0.22  0.12   0.07     0.105
        NY      0.11  0.29   0.13     0.160
```

or:

```
In [83]: df.groupby('State').mean()
Out[83]:
       White        AA  Black  Hispanic
State
NJ      0.30  0.153333   0.11  0.203333
NY      0.11  0.290000   0.13  0.160000
```